# Where is the template for the 'standard' format of a post in the theme twentythirteen?

Tags: templates, get-template-part

I have selected the 'standard' format for a post:

[image]

I am now trying to edit the layout of posts, in index.php I can see the following line:

get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format()

In the directory of twentythirteen I see several content pages which I am assuming is the post layout for the different formats I can select in the post.

- content-aside.php
- content-audio.php
- content-chat.php
- content-gallery,php
- content-image.php
- content-link.php
- content-none.php
- content-quote.php
- content-status.php
- content-video.php

I would have expected to see a content.php or content-standard.php, but I can't find anything that affects the layout. Where is this file (if it exists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress Twenty Thirteen uses default content.php file for the display of standard post format. Other post formats uses their corresponding files for display of content. In absence of particular template for post format, default content.php is used.

The content.php file should be located at **wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/content.php**